# Apache FOP - XSL FO - count Intentionally left blank pages

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

**My XSL**:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="normal" page-height="210mm" page-width="148mm"> 
            <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin="28mm 2mm 10mm 8mm" />
            <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="12mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="blank" page-height="210mm" page-width="148mm">
            <fo:region-body/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="header-blank" extent="210mm"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="12mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="not-blank" master-reference="normal"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" master-reference="blank"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" force-page-count="end-on-even">   
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica" text-align="center" margin="6mm 2mm 0mm 8mm">
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica" margin="0mm 2mm 0mm 8mm">
            P <fo:page-number/>/<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="TheVeryLastPage"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-blank">
        <fo:block text-align-last="center" font-size="9.5" margin-top="75mm">
            Intentionally left blank
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block id="TheVeryLastPage"> </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>
```

**Output**:
First page: P 1/1
Second page: P 2/1

**Desired output**:
First page: P 1/2
Second page: P 2/2

How can I include the Intentionally left blank page in my page count?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I guess, you are using Apache FOP, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, Wrote that in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't work that way, because your block bearing the id `TheVeryLastPage` does not appear in the last page that has been automatically generated. Correct numbering will be generated only if the additional blank page (*intentionally left blank*) does not need to be generated.

Apache FOP, which is sometimes and unfortunately buggy or limited regarding page number retrieval (in particular, if you use `<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="">` that might help in your case, for example by setting the id on the `<fo:block>` that is use to display the page numbering, it should work properly - and it actually does with a commercial renderer such as Antenna House because it is able to perform a 2-pass generation process).

The only way to this is with FOP as follows:

1. set the id on the `<fo:page-sequence>`
2. use a `<fo:page-number-citation-last>`

Your modified code will look like this:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="document" force-page-count="end-on-even" id="TheVeryLastPage">   
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:block font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica" text-align="center" margin="6mm 2mm 0mm 8mm">
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        <fo:block font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica" margin="0mm 2mm 0mm 8mm">
            P <fo:page-number/>/<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="TheVeryLastPage" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:static-content flow-name="header-blank">
        <fo:block text-align-last="center" font-size="9.5" margin-top="75mm">
            Intentionally left blank
            <!--fo:block id="TheVeryLastPage" /-->
        </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>Thy hand, belinda, darkness shades me.</fo:block>
         <fo:block>On thy bosom let me rest.</fo:block>
         <fo:block>More I would, but death invades me.</fo:block>
         <fo:block>Death is now a welcome guest.</fo:block>

         <fo:block>When I am laid in earth, may my wrongs create</fo:block>
         <fo:block>No trouble in thy breast.</fo:block>
         <fo:block>Remember me, but ah! forget my fate.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```